# iphone popup how to? what control to use

Tags: iphone, modal-dialog, uipopover

I want to make a popup type of layer on the iPhone 4. Is that possible? Like in this screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the iPad, you can use the built in UIPopoverController to achieve a very similar control. There is no built in control that shows like a popover in the iPhone. You will either have to create your own or use a different control.

There is an open source Popover for iPhone. I've never used it but I think it will fulfil your needs: https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover

Comment: The sample Application you have given is really suits as same as in ipad(uipopovercontroller)..Thank you

Comment: yes, the only problem is that I have to make it for iphone 4 :(

Answer (score -1):

That’s a custom control. There’s a system pop-up control on the iPad called `UIPopOverController`, but I don’t think it’s available on the iPhone. See also [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878332) about popovers on iPhone.