# UIPopoverController for iPhone

Tags: iphone, uipopovercontroller

Does anyone know of how I would go about creating a UIPopoverController like the one found in Tweetbot form Tapbots? For months I have been trying to figure this out and gave up thinking it wasn't possible. When Tweetbot received an update with this, it made realize it is possible but I still can't seem to figure it out. Does anyone know of classes I could download that has an identical UIPopover?

Thanks

**Edit: http://d.pr/LPI9**

Comment: A picture might help explain what you are going for.

Answer (score 1):

Popover controllers are for use exclusively on iPad devices. Attempting to create one on other devices results in an exception.

If you need custom popOverController check this link
[Custom uipopovercontroller for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878332/uipopovercontroller-for-iphone-currently-only-available-for-ipad?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

```
  TestTableViewController *vc = [[TestTableViewController alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

    [self addChildViewController:vc];

    [self.view addSubview:vc.view];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:vc.view];
    [vc.view setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 200)];
```

You can create a child view as uipopviewcontroller , beware not add childview on a scrollview , otherwise the scroll effect vanishes .