# How to show popover on selecting an image

Tags: ipad, popover

I am trying to show a popover on selection of a image in my iPad.So how can i do it?

Comment: Try this [code][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878332/uipopovercontroller-for-iphone-currently-only-available-for-ipad

Comment: If i want to show in ipad then how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Put a transparent button on the image and of the size of the image and then use the UIPopoverController to launch a pop over view...  hope this helps.

Comment: Without using button is there any solution present?

Comment: UIImage is not derived from UIControl ... So i dont think you will be able to do it.. What is wrong with a transparent button..

Comment: – presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated: i am trying this method but i am still unable to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *mousePoint = [touches anyObject];

    CGPoint point = [mousePoint locationInView:self.view];
    _didClickMark=CGRectContainsPoint(mImageView.frame, point);

       if(_didClickMark)
       // show popover
}
```

This might help you.