# Error: exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'Pad.'

Tags: iphone, ios

I am new to Objective C.
I want to call a pop up view on a button click.
I am getting this error when I am running my application using following code

if(self.SharePopoverView==nil)
    {

```
    self.SharePopoverView = [[shareView alloc] autorelease ];
    *****************this line code creating some problem*********
    self.SharepopOverController = [[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:SharePopoverView] autorelease];
```

---

```
}


[SharepopOverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:self permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
```

I am getting the error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController initWithContentViewController:] called when not running under UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad.'

Answer (score 3):

If you are running this on iPhone it would not work as `UIPopoverController` is only built for iPad. But you can refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878332/uipopovercontroller-for-iphone-currently-only-available-for-ipad) to get it working on iPhone.